# How to iterate through the all the body objects

Tags: javascript, foreach, cypress, each

I want to assert if my response.body does not contain some provided value. The body has let's assume 10 objects. All the objects have "id" field. How to use some kind of each or forEach on the request response? I know that I can use e.g.

```
expect(response.body[0].requestId).not.eq(value);
expect(response.body[1].requestId).not.eq(value);
expect(response.body[2].requestId).not.eq(value);
expect(response.body[3].requestId).not.eq(value);
```

but I don't know how to code it in a more optimized way.

I prepared the array with:

```
    const bodyObjects = [
      'body[0]',
      'body[1]',
      'body[2]',
      'body[3]',
      'body[4]',
    ];
```

My code

```
it.only("Something "A" should not see something "B"", () => {
    const bodyObjects = [
      'body[0]',
      'body[1]',
      'body[2]',
      'body[3]',
      'body[4]',
    ];
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: Cypress.env("URL",
      auth: {
        bearer: token,
      },
      body: {
        id: someId,
      },
    }).then((response, $bodyObjects) => {
      responseId = response.body.id;
      expect(response.status).to.eq(201);
      **MY POTENTIAL ASSERTION**
    })
  });
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve]. For an actual [mcve] we need the actual content of `response.body` and not only a vague description of it.

Comment: _"My code"_ has a syntax error (which the broken syntax highlighting should have told you ;))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering `response.body` is an array, you can use a `forEach` loop to iterate through them:

```js
responde.body.forEach(res => {
  expect(res.requestId).not.eq(value)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a `forEach` like this:

```js
it.only('Something "A" should not see something "B""', () => {
  const bodyObjects = ['body[0]', 'body[1]', 'body[2]', 'body[3]', 'body[4]']
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.env('URL'),
    auth: {
      bearer: token,
    },
    body: {
      id: someId,
    },
  }).then((response, $bodyObjects) => {
    responseId = response.body.id
    expect(response.status).to.eq(201)
    bodyObjects.forEach((bodyObject) => {
      expect(response[bodyObject].requestId).not.eq(value)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: You're legend @Alapan Das . Thank you. you answered almost all my Cypress doubts here, on stack overall flow ;)

Comment: @UmeshSulakude Thank you for your kind words.